# How do I parse HTML data loaded via an Ajax response?

Tags: ruby, html-parsing, mechanize

I click on a link, and it sends the Ajax request which then populates the page. Here is the link I am parsing:

```
http://dell.force.com/partner/spf__partnersearch?c=us&l=en_US
```

On this page is a search link. When I click on it without filling the form displayed and it then sends an Ajax request and populates the section below with the content.

How do I read it with Mechanize? I am not able to find an accurate answer.

Comment: If you're clicking on a link that sends an Ajax request, you're doing it a browser, which understands how to execute JavaScript. Mechanize doesn't know how to do anything with JavaScript, which means you can't parse or execute it. The end result is that you can't do this with Mechanize.

Comment: Thank you very much, i am searching some other way.

Answer (score 4):

Mechanize will not execute javascript so you need to use a different approach. One way is to use a so-called headless browser, for example [Watir in combination with the `headless` gem](http://watirwebdriver.com/headless/) or [PhantomJS with Poltergeist for Ruby bindings](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist).

Comment: This answer helped me and i am using watir-webdriver. Happy :)

Comment: It's just so simple to scrape this with mechanize. Yes it's javascript, but all the javascript does is submit the form.

Comment: You're right. I just read "Ajax" and started thinking "ok mechanize won't handle that". Mea culpa. +1 to your solution

Answer (score 1):

You just submit the form. That action just submits the form and does something with the response.